# Properties of the sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, total-variation

[image]
Given a sequence $\{a_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{Z}},$ consider the sequence defined by $b_i:=F(a_{i-1},a_{i},a_{i+1}),$ where $F:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is increasing in each of the variable, and $F(a,a,a)=a.$ Suppose total variation of the sequence $\{a_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{Z}}$ is finite i.e. $$\sup\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{i=-k}^k |a_i-a_{i-1}| < \infty$$ then how to prove the following

$$\sup\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{i=-k}^k |b_i-b_{i-1}| \leq \sup\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{i=-k}^k |a_i-a_{i-1}| $$

I have an intuitive idea of the proof but some how unable to give a rigorous proof.

The idea is local extremas of $b_i$ are bounded below and above by some $a_m$ and $a_n$ because of the monotonicity..How to give a rigorous proof?

I could not succeed with mathematical induction either.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are claiming is not true... due to the following counter example

Define $F(x,y,z)=max(x,z),$ clearly $F$ is increasing in each of the variable.

define the sequence by 
\begin{equation}a_i=
{ \left\{ \begin{array}{ccl}
1 & \, \mbox{if}\,i=0, \\
0 & \, \mbox{otherwise}\,,
\end{array}\right.} 
\end{equation}
Then $b_i$ turns out to be

\begin{equation}b_i=
{ \left\{ \begin{array}{ccl}
1 & \, \mbox{if}\,i=-1,1, \\
0 & \, \mbox{otherwise}\,,
\end{array}\right.} 
\end{equation}
and we have,
$$\sup\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{i=-k}^k |a_i-a_{i-1}|=2$$

$$\sup\limits_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{i=-k}^k |b_i-b_{i-1}| =4$$